# Reverse while loop python

Tags: python, while-loop, reverse

Reversing a while loop. I am having issues grasping the concept of reversing the while loop. Please Help

```
    b=1 
    while b=<6:
        d=1
        while d<=b:
            print("1",end="")
        d+=1
        print()
        b+=1
```

Comment: I would recommend cleaning up the indentation. I am guessing you have two nested loops, but as it is written, this won't run in Python.

Looks like it prints a bunch of 1 in a triangular form, but a clearer description of your problem would help.
Cheers, --B

Comment: Start with `b = 6` and decrement?

Answer (score 0):

```
b = 1
while b <= 6:
    d = 1
    while d <= b:
        print("1", end="")
        d += 1
    print()
    b += 1
```

print:

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
```

Not sure what you are really looking for...

Comment: to turn this around so it starts with the 6 '1' and end with the. first '1'

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If to reverse the order, the first loop increment and goes forward and second loop decrement:

```
    b = 1
while b <= 6:
    d = 6
    while d >= b:
        print("1", end="")
        d -= 1
    print()
    b += 1
```

Is this what you are looking for?

print:

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```